# In python how can I use/manipulate an object defined in a script from a function defined in an imported module?

Tags: python

This might be a terribly simple one, but I don't know what's the "right" answer. Assume that I have a script

```
import utils
bar = 1
utils.foo()
print bar
```

Furthermore, the module `utils` is:

```
def foo():
  bar = bar+1
```

As given above, I ,obviously, get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'bar' referenced before assignment
```

**How can I use `bar` inside `foo()`?** In my specific case, I don't really want to alter `foo`, but I *do* need to be able to use it and its state inside `foo()`.

One workaround would be to pass `bar` to `foo()`:

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar+1
```

And replace the third line in the script: `bar = utils.foo(bar)`.

However, this feels like a cumbersome solution; in particular if bar is a complex object.

I am interested in a *best-practice* approach the case described above.

Comment: For this kind of use, the practice you're suggesting is definitely valid and is not a workaround at all

Comment: And what if `foo()` has to handle dozen of parameters `bar1,bar2,...`? Passing them around feels sub-optimal.

Comment: It might be that I have a fundamental design flaw that leads to the need mentioned above. If this is the case please enlight me :)

Comment: Your code breaks the principle of loose coupling between modules. For example you decide to use utils.foo in any other module but you can't do it because you need to init 'bar' variable firstly. But in this case you expose the internal structure of utils.foo of your module which is wrong. This is the reason why it doesn't work in python because the original idea of python code organisation is to create independent modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you want to alter foo? If you import a module, you want to use its functionality. If the foo function is without parameters, then bar or other variables in it are used in the module utils itself. If you want to use a function with values that are not inside the module, then:

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar+1
```

is totally acceptable.

EDIT:
// When you create class foo1, just set bar in the constructor.
class foo1:
    def **init**(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

Image this situation:

```
import someModule

# now you want to use a function of this module
foo()
```

Maybe then there would be an error like: bar is not defined or whatever --> modules are not loosely coupled. Either make the function foo as you proposed with parameters (totally acceptable) or set the bar value via a constructor or setBar method.

Comment: I don't mind changing `foo()`. See my comments above; I hope you can refer to them in your answer.

Comment: I've edited my anser. Your proposed solution is not a workaround it's the way you do it.

Answer (score 0):

> **I am interested in a best-practice approach the case described above**

As you describe, `bar` is an argument to `foo`, and the best practice way to pass an argument to a function is to pass it as an argument to the function.

in `utils.py`:

```
def foo(bar):
    return bar+1
```

And in your other script:

```
import utils
bar = 1
bar = utils.foo(bar)
print bar
```

This *is* the best practice approach. It follows the correct semantics. It is also testable:

```
import unittest
import utils

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.bar = 1

    def test_bar(self):
        self.assertEquals(2, utils.foo(self.bar))
```

Comment: Is it still the best practice if `foo()` manipulated a long list of objects that are defined in the script?

Comment: Yes. Better to have testable functionality, than untestable side effects.